# Common meaning of conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history

If you look for conjugation in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation#Mathematics), you find around 15 different mathematical meanings for this concept.

Is there something in common to all those meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the common property of all of them is that the conjugate of the conjugate is the original element. So in more mathy language, all things called conjugate are a map from a class of objects to itself with the property that the square of the map is the identity.

Edit to include postmortes comment: In general a map from a class of objects to itself that squares to the identity is called an *involution*. Some very common or natural involutions are called conjugate but I think the distinction here is convention and common usage.

Comment: Actually an *involution* is a map which is the identity when it's applied twice successively, and conjugation is an example of an involution :)

Comment: @postmortes very true. Do you want to write that up as a separate answer or should I edit mine to add that in?

Comment: edit yours, I think you have a nice answer already here :)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at a Latin - 'some other language' dictionary then (in the case of English) you will find always something like this

[image]

The common in all the "conjugation" related concepts is that something is related/connected to something else. P. ex. the complex number and its complex conjugate.